# Area 51 Profile Reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

I am wondering how my friend has managed to get 151 reputation on the Area 51 network.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/33473/johnhodkinson?tab=stats

However when I click on the reputation tab, it shows no reputation activity.  He has 0 answers and 0 questions. Should the reputation display 101 or the additional reputation be shown in the reputation activity window?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Association bonus gives you 100 reputation
>
> Verifying your email gives 50 more

Comment: At stackoverflow I can see my Association Bonus(100 points) at my reputation list. Why Area 51 doesn't show it?

Comment: @kamaci - the Area51 code base was forked from the primary one *years* ago, major changes like the reputation overhaul didn't go there, since Area51 itself is getting a major overhaul in the coming months we're not spending a ton of development effort to make the current one match 100%

Answer (score 2):

Your friend reached 200 reputation on another site and got the associate account +100 bonus. Every site he joins with Stack Exchange will now have a min of 101 reputation.