# A second verification email from Area 51, almost 2 years later

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, email-verification

The accepted answer to the question about [Area 51 Profile Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159865/area-51-profile-reputation) states that in order to have 151 reputation on Area51:

> Association bonus gives you 100 reputation
>
> Verifying your email gives 50 more

I joined Area51 in February 2013 and [already have 151 reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/78798/james-donnelly) on Area51. I've also backed a couple of proposals, such as Reverse Engineering.

However I've just received the following email:

[image: Example]

This comes after having already received and read (and presumably already clicked to verify) a verification email from Area 51 back in February 2013:

[image: Inbox]

Is this a bug?

Comment: a51 is very borked

Comment: Maybe you edited your area51 profile and changed the email field? Then you get a link to verify the email address, which stay even if you edit back to the old email. Clicking it would indeed send another verification email.

Comment: Another option is that somebody else put your email in his/her email field then sent the verification. Do you happen to have a common email address that can be misused by mistake?

Comment: @ShadowWizard my Area 51 profile is linked to this one. I haven't changed my profile's email address since I first joined Stack Overflow. The address I use for all Stack Exchange sites is through my own domain.

Comment: So it's weird... check the URL of the "click here to verify" in the email. It should be something like `http://area51.stackexchange.com/email/verify/[uid]/[key]` - is the "uid" value is really your Area 51 user id i.e. 78798? If not, you can use this to see who sent this verification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep, definitely me. I've since clicked on the verification email link to see if it increased my reputation by a further 50, but my reputation hasn't changed.

Comment: So I fear only a dev can look into it properly, hope one will pass here soon enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you edit your profile elsewhere on the network?

The verification email from 2013 was sent to another email address. Your user history on Area 51 basically looks like this:

```
James Donnelly -> User has verified their email address xxxxx@mydomain.com 1 hour ago (0 rep)
James Donnelly -> User is emailed 'Verify Email' 2 hours ago
[...]
James Donnelly -> User has verified their email address name@example.me Feb 26 '13 at 16:08 (50 rep)
James Donnelly -> User is emailed 'Verify Email' Feb 26 '13 at 16:03
```

Without digging much further... it looks like your email changed and we re-sent the verification email to the new address.

Comment: Interesting! About a month or two ago I linked my Stack Exchange account to my Facebook and Google accounts. I haven't received any similar messages on any of the other sites I frequently visit on the SE network.

Comment: I changed my own email to try to repro but did not get verification email until I explicitly clicked the link to re-send it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Area 51 is the only one that has a concept of a "verified email".

Comment: I see. Perhaps that's the cause then. Thanks for your time.