# Still need to verify my Area 51 Email even though I verified it in the past

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, email-verification

I know this has been asked before, but I don't know where to find the answer. I've gotten a verification email on the past and clicked on it. But now, it's saying I still need to verify my E-mail.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247995/152859), you most likely changed your email on one of the sites at some point, and new verification email was sent. Either you missed it, or used a fake address, and the email was lost.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm, nope, doesn't look like the same thing. I'll have to dig more later.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, good luck with the digging! :)

Comment: @captaindogfish Can you add a screenshot? I don't see the verification request on your profile (and I normally would). Have you tried verifying the email again anyway?

Comment: The issue was solved. Not sure how, but it was. Did someone fix it? :)

Comment: @captaindogfish Not that I'm aware of, but hey, all's well that ends well. :)

Comment: Have seen this myself with some people I was sitting next to as they tried to join an Area 51 proposal. They received the email, clicked on it but no verification resulted. Tried several times. Logging out and back in. Still nothing. Request the email again. Same result.